# Add or subtract a number based on the combination of columns/conditions

Tags: r

I would like to adjust `hdl`, `ldl`, and `trig` by adding or subtracting a constant based on the combination of the dummy variable columns. The constants are:

| med | hdl | ldl | trig |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| med1 | -3.5 | 34.5 | 20.1 |
| med2 | -6.3 | 24.7 | 0 |
| med3 | -5 | 42.3 | 12 |
| med4 | 0 | 23 | 22 |
| med5 | -2.1 | 12 | 22.2 |

Specifically, the rules are:

1. When a person is only taking one 1 medication, then add/subtract the corresponding constant. For example, For ID#12 who's only taking med5:

- Adj_hdl = original hdl - 2.1
- Adj_ldl = original ldl + 12
- Adj_trig = original trig + 22.2

2. When a person is taking more than 1 medication, the the adjusted hdl/ldl/trig would be added/substracted using the constant with **the largest absolute value** .

For example, for ID #1, he/she's taking med2, med3, and med5. Then his/her adjusted lipids would be:

- Adj_hdl = original hdl - 6.3 (since among med2,3,5, med2 has the constant with the largest absolute value across all meds for hdl)
- Adj_ldl = original ldl + 42.3
- Adj_trig = original trig + 22.2

As such, the end product would be a data set with additional 3 columns, `adj_hdl`, `adj_ldl`, and `adj_trig` for each of the IDs.

Mock data set:

```
set.seed(100)
id = 1:100
hdl = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 3)
ldl = rnorm(100, mean = 120, sd = 10)
trig = rnorm(100, mean = 150, sd = 12)
med1 = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.4)
med2 = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.6)
med3 = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.55)
med4 = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.45)
med5 = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.72)

data = cbind(id, hdl, ldl, trig, med1, med2, med3, med4, med5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's messy but I believe it works.

```
library(dplyr)
d <- as.data.frame(data)

df: Comparison dataframe
   med  hdl  ldl trig
1 med1 -3.5 34.5 20.1
2 med2 -6.3 24.7  0.0
3 med3 -5.0 42.3 12.0
4 med4  0.0 23.0 22.0
5 med5 -2.1 12.0 22.2

d |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(across(ldl:trig, ~ .x + max(df[[cur_column()]][df$med %in% (colnames(cur_data()[5:9])[which(cur_data()[5:9] == 1)])]),
                .names = "adj_{.col}")) |> 
  mutate(adj_hdl = hdl - max(abs(df$hdl[df$med %in% (colnames(cur_data()[5:9])[which(cur_data()[5:9] == 1)])])))
```

***Revised*** (added ifelse instead of second mutate)

```
d |>  
rowwise() |>  
mutate(across(hdl:trig, ~ { 
adj <- max(abs(df[[cur_column()]][df$med %in% (colnames(cur_data()[5:9 [which(cur_data()[5:9] == 1)])]))     
ifelse(cur_column() == "hdl", .x - adj, .x + adj)   }, .names = "adj_{.col}"))



# A tibble: 100 × 12
# Rowwise: 
      id   hdl   ldl  trig  med1  med2  med3  med4  med5 adj_ldl adj_trig adj_hdl
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  48.5  117.  150.     0     1     1     0     1    159.     173.    42.2
 2     2  50.4  134.  146.     0     0     1     0     1    176.     168.    45.4
 3     3  49.8  115.  160.     0     0     1     0     1    158.     182.    44.8
 4     4  52.7  128.  156.     0     1     1     1     1    171.     178.    46.4
 5     5  50.4  105.  162.     0     1     0     1     1    130.     184.    44.1
 6     6  51.0  116.  138.     1     1     1     1     1    158.     160.    44.7
 7     7  48.3  112.  143.     0     1     1     0     1    155.     165.    42.0
 8     8  52.1  116.  138.     0     0     0     1     1    139.     160.    50.0
 9     9  47.5  132.  114.     1     0     1     0     1    175.     136.    42.5
10    10  48.9  119.  154.     0     1     0     0     0    144.     154.    42.6
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain why did you separate `adj_hdl` from `adj_ldl` and `adj_trig`?

Comment: Because one was negative. And you need the absolute value. If I put them all in one then the adj hdl would be add to the number instead of subtracted. You can switch up the order of the mutations if you'd like it to follow the past order.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I ran the updated code but got the following error: ``Error: unexpected '}' in "               ifelse(cur_column() == "hdl", .x - adj, .x + adj)   }"``